# is there any way that ican directly poll consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka I created 3 consumers with the same group id. logically, these 3 consumers are in one group, right.

but individually I'm polling each of the consumers, is there any way to poll the consumer group?
my doubt is:
 1. can I directly poll consumer Group?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They will form a consumer group.

No, you cannot "poll the group". But I am not sure in the first place why you want to do this (or what you exactly mean by this). The idea of a consumer group is to allow scaling out. Thus, as long as a single consumer can handle the load, there is no reason to use more than one consumer. However, if you load cannot be handled by a single instance, you would run multiple consumer is parallel (most likely on different machines) to allow scale out.